# JSX generate divs and push to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a structure of the form:

```
var circle = {
   'one':   {items: []},
   'two':   {items: []},
   'three': {items: []},
   'four':  {items: []}
 };
```

Each `items` array should hold 10 unique divs, like this:

`circle.one.items` array should hold:

`<div className="item item-1">1</div>`
...
`<div className="item item-10">10</div>`

...

`circle.four.items` array should hold:

`<div className="item item-31">31</div>`
...
`<div className="item item-40">40</div>`

And I'm using the structure like this:

```
<div className="circle-one">
    {circle.one.items}
</div>
```

How do I populate the `items` arrays with those divs?

Comment: is it a div object or a string, you need?

Comment: Define what you'd consider elegant. You could just use nested loops. Some might consider that elegant (or elegant enough) or at least pretty readable. What have you actually tried so far and why don't you like it? This is feeling like code review...

Comment: @NinaScholz, object: `arr.push(<div className={"item item-"+i}></div>)`  @MattBurland, by elegant I mean that I don't have any idea how to JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an array and loop the array for the items.

```js
var circle = { 'one': { items: [] }, 'two': { items: [] }, 'three': { items: [] }, 'four': { items: [] } };

['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'].forEach(function (k, i) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        circle[k].items.push('<div className="item item-' + (i * 10 + j) + '">' + (i * 10 + j) + '</div>');
    }
});

console.log(circle);
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, this is what I was looking for. PS, correct JSX format: `circle[k].items.push(<div className={"item item-"+(i * 10 + j) }>{(i * 10 + j)}</div>);`

Comment: Why not use for...in on the Object circle and then use this.items.push?

Comment: @Rikin, `for ... in` can not guaranty the order, which is necessary here (as well as `Object.keys`).

Comment: Thanks for following up, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have you starting object, then a simple nested loop would work just fine:

```
var keys = ["one","two","three","four"];
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {    // Note: you might want to avoid the magic number here
        circle[keys[i]].items.push(createDiv(i * 10 + j + 1));
    }
}
```

where `createDiv` is a function that takes the number for your `item-xx` and returns the actual div you want.

The one thing to note here is that I have defined an array with the keys to your object in the order that I want them. You *should not* rely on, for example `Object.keys` returning the keys in any defined order.

Comment: Thank you Matt, in my attempts I was using `Object.keys`. Your code also does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you wanted those divs as strings. Anyway you can update `populateItems` function below to return what you want.

```
var mapping = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four: 4};

function populateItems(n) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var curr = i+(n-1)*10;
    output.push('<div className="item item-'+curr+'">+'curr+'</div>');
  }
  return output;
}

for (p in circle) {
  circle[p].items = populateItems(mapping[p]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use underscore/lodash you could do this:

```
_.each(circle, (obj) => {
    obj.items = _.map(_.range(10), (n) => {
        return <div className={'item item'+n}>n</div>
    });
});
```

my variable naming is pretty terrible btw!